config.getstring returns null only if the config has more than 3 "points"
This is my config.yml:
gui:
  title: "This is the GUI's name"
items:
  feather: "This is item feather"
  cookie:
    hello: "Hello, here's a cookie"

And here's the part of code:
String guiTitle = config.getString("gui.title");
String itemsFeather = config.getString("items.feather"); 
String itemsOnTest = config.getString("items.cookie.hello");

getLogger().info("Gui title: " + guiTitle);
getLogger().info("Items feather: " + itemsFeather);
getLogger().info("Items on test: " + itemsOnTest);

The first 2 getLoggers show the correct text from the config, while itemsOnTest returns null. As long as I use 2 "names" in the config like:
Example 1:
  test: "This is a test"

It works and shows the "This is a test", while if it's more than 2 like this:
items:
  on:
    test: "hello"

Then items.on.test won't show "hello" but null.

Key as on/off/true/false seems to be reserved keyword, and create issue. It's not because of 3 steps.
I simply suggest you to change the keyword used to something like enabled, and this should works fine.

can't believe i spent hours raging when it was that easy... thanks man, solved the issue

With pleasure. We all fall in issue like this, it's very disturbing but when we found it, it's easy to fix so it's the most important. Remember it to don't do it again ;)
